# How can i get the service ref after i changed org.apache.felix.scr.annotations to org.osgi.service.component.annotations

Tags: annotations, osgi, apache-karaf, onos, apache-karaf-feature

the command error

```
20:25:41.655 ERROR [AtomixManager] bundle org.onosproject.onos-core-primitives:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT (234)[org.onosproject.store.atomix.impl.AtomixManager(67)] : The activate method has thrown an exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.atomix.cluster.protocol.HeartbeatMembershipProtocol$Type cannot be cast to class io.atomix.utils.NamedType (io.atomix.cluster.protocol.HeartbeatMembershipProtocol$Type is in unnamed module of loader io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphClassLoader @3ade9526; io.atomix.utils.NamedType is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @ea65217)
        at io.atomix.core.registry.ClasspathScanningRegistry.lambda$null$1(ClasspathScanningRegistry.java:80)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at io.atomix.core.registry.ClasspathScanningRegistry.lambda$new$2(ClasspathScanningRegistry.java:74)
        at java.base/java.util.Map.computeIfAbsent(Map.java:1003)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Collections.java:2682)
        at io.atomix.core.registry.ClasspathScanningRegistry.<init>(ClasspathScanningRegistry.java:68)
        at io.atomix.core.registry.ClasspathScanningRegistry.<init>(ClasspathScanningRegistry.java:43)
        at io.atomix.core.registry.ClasspathScanningRegistry$Builder.build(ClasspathScanningRegistry.java:215)
......
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:328)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:929)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:915)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:984)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:752)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enableInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:674)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$1.run(AbstractComponentManager.java:461)
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.ComponentActorThread.run(ComponentActorThread.java:114)
```

I add some compile dependency
such as in features.xml

```
<bundle>mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.resource/1.0.0</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.service.component/1.4.0</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.service.component.annotations/1.4.0</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations/1.4.0</bundle>
```

but it has nothing to fix the problem
this is what i get, i can't fix it
the console can't get the bundle or service or component etc.
anyone can give some advice for me,
thank you in advance!

Comment: this `ClassCastException` is due to classloader for the two classes being different. this would usually happen if the bundle trying to get the service ref has its own copy of that class instead of using the one provided by osgi runtime (exported by another bundle).

Comment: Thanks to give me the clue, and i had fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

the cause is that io.github.classgraph loads class io.atomix.utils.NamedType io.atomix.cluster.protocol.HeartbeatMembershipProtocol$Type  while org.apache.felix.framework loads class io.atomix.utils.NamedType, but HeartbeatMembershipProtocol$Type should be typecast to NamedType。

The solved method is to add some DynamicImport-Package attribute in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>io.atomix.cluster.*,io.atomix.primitive.*,io.atomix.core.*,io.atomix.protocols.*</DynamicImport-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

so when your bundle is loaded, the dependency jars will be loaded.

thanks those who give me clues!